# replace character from digit using replaceAll not working in java

Tags: java, string, replace

```
item.setPrice(e.text().replaceAll("[^\\d\\.]", ""));
```

I want to replace all the character and special characters coming inside displaying Price value.....

But in one case `Rs.1200.20` it is returning the value `.1200.00`

I want to avoid that `.` from the beginning.
I want output like **1200.00** not **.1200.00**
 How can i do that?

Comment: Note: no need to escape the dot in a character class; `"[^\\d.]"` works equally well

Comment: but it does not give the out put i want ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"[^\\d]+[.]"` to replace that and also plain `"Rs."` to replace specifically.

Comment: yea this works.. thanks mate....  and i dont want to plain RS. like this because sometimes u used different countries data. so it might be different input

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your prices are in the form `xxxx.yyy` where `x` and `y` are digits, you can use this code:

```
private static final Pattern PRICE_PATTERN
    = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");

// In code...
final Matcher m = PRICE_PATTERN.matcher(e.text());

item.setPrice(m.find() ? m.group() : "INVALID");
```

Doesn't handle *all* cases (for instance "1.2.3", "hello1.2world3.4", etc etc); it will only try and find the first valid price in the input string.

Comment: my price is in the form   RS.120.33 and i want output like 120.33 . that means xxx.yyy.zzz where xxx is character and yyy and zzz are digits.. i want to avoid xxx and first .